# row_number() over(order by varchar2 column) is taking more time in oracle 12c?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I'm applying row_number() over(order by varchar2 column) on table is having 2 million records but is taking more time in oracle 12c.

Plan hash value: 193104477

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                           | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                                |  1631K|   628M|       |   257K  (1)| 00:00:11 |
|   1 |  WINDOW SORT                 |                                |  1631K|   628M|   670M|   257K  (1)| 00:00:11 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                  |                                |  1631K|   628M|  8128K|   117K  (1)| 00:00:05 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL         | SYS_USER                       |   108K|  6856K|       |  2466   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    HASH JOIN                 |                                |  1631K|   527M|  2608K| 87280   (1)| 00:00:04 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL        | CHANGE_REQUEST                 | 45210 |  2075K|       |  3850   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     HASH JOIN                |                                |  1632K|   454M|  3800K| 59840   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|   7 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL       | SYS_USER                       |   108K|  2531K|       |  2467   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |      HASH JOIN               |                                |  1632K|   417M|  7800K| 35566   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|*  9 |       HASH JOIN              |                                | 62854 |  7058K|       |  1826   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |        INDEX FAST FULL SCAN  | COMPINDEX_SYSID_NAME_NI        |  2716 |   143K|       |    15   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |        VIEW                  | index$_join$_003               | 69097 |  4116K|       |  1810   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |         HASH JOIN            |                                |       |       |       |            |          |
|* 13 |          INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| I001823ASSIGNMENT_GROUPSYSAPPR | 69097 |  4116K|       |  1008   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |          INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| SYSAPPROVAL_GROUP_SYS_ID       | 69097 |  4116K|       |   743   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL      | SYSAPPROVAL_APPROVER           |  1841K|   268M|       | 18984   (1)| 00:00:01 |
```

Below is the query i am using.

```
SELECT cr.number_x AS UNIQUE_KEY,
        row_number() over(ORDER BY sa.sys_id) AS COUNTER,
        sa.sys_updated_on AS "DATE"
FROM snowdb.sysapproval_approver sa,
     snowdb.change_request cr,
     snowdb.sysapproval_group sag,
     snowdb.sys_user_group sug,
     snowdb.sys_user su,
     snowdb.sys_user su1
WHERE sa."GROUP_X"=sag.sys_id
  AND sa.sysapproval=cr.sys_id
  AND sag.assignment_group=sug.sys_id
  AND sa.approver=su.sys_id
  AND sa.sys_updated_by=su1.employee_number
```

Comment: Is there an index created on `varchar2 column` ? If no, then RDBMS must sort all 2 million rows on this column to obtain row_number values, and the sort must take some time. If there is an index, then RDBMS must not to sort, but uses that index.

Comment: @krokodilko is right. I strongly recommend you create index for `varchar2 column` at first.

Comment: @krokodilko: Yes, already there is UNIQUE index on that column.

Comment: Please attach the whole query to the question. Please also run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR your_query` and then `SELECT * FROM table(Dbms_Xplan.display)`, and finally copy and append **a whole** result of last query to the question **as a text, not a bitmap**.

Comment: SELECT   cr.number_x                                  AS UNIQUE_KEY
 row_number() over(order by sa.sys_id)        AS COUNTER,
  sa.sys_updated_on                                   AS "DATE",
  FROM snowdb.sysapproval_approver sa
    ,snowdb.change_request cr
    ,snowdb.sysapproval_group sag
    ,snowdb.sys_user_group sug
    ,snowdb.sys_user su
    ,snowdb.sys_user su1
WHERE sa."GROUP_X"=sag.sys_id
AND   sa.sysapproval=cr.sys_id
AND   sag.assignment_group=sug.sys_id
AND   sa.approver=su.sys_id
AND   sa.sys_updated_by=su1.employee_number